# Can't find Android Compatibility Package on SDK Manager

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, android-actionbar

I want to start learning to work with Fragments and I want to install the Compatibility package for pre 3.0 versions of Android.

However, I can't seem to find this package on the SDK manager. Here's everything I see:

[image]

Also, I want to install Action Bar Sherlock to work with Action Bars. On the ACS website it says "If you’re using the Eclipse Development Environment with the ADT plugin version 0.9.7 or greater you can include this as a library project" -

how do I include library projects?

Thanks

Comment: In this tutorial it shows "compatibility package" on SDK:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/

Answer (score 12):

It's called the **Android Support Package**.

[image]

**Referencing Library Projects**

Assuming you're using Eclipse, [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) is how you reference a library project (highlights):

1. In the Package Explorer, right-click the dependent project and select Properties.
2. In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
3. Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.
4. From the list of available library projects, select a project and click OK.
5. When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.
6. Click OK to close the Properties window.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed this in the ABSherlock site: "Note: If you were previously using the Android compatability library you must remove its .jar. ActionBarSherlock is built on top of the compatability library and comes bundled with its classes."------ does this mean i only have to include action bar sherlock and and I'll be have to work with fragments and the action bar?

Comment: @tyb Yes, if ABS states that it's built **on top** of the compatability library and **already** comes bundled with its classes, then **don't** install the Android Support Package and **only** include and reference the the ABS library.

Answer (score 2):

To include library projects, right-click on your project and select Properties, then Android. You will see a form to include library projects. Click Add. (The library project must be loaded in Eclipse.)

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed this in the ABSherlock site:

Note: If you were previously using the Android compatability library you must remove its .jar. ActionBarSherlock is built on top of the compatability library and comes bundled with its classes.------ does this mean i only have to include action bar sherlock and and I'll be have to work with fragments and the action bar?

Comment: I've never used ABS but it sure sounds like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem when the support package is already installed then uninstalling the support package through the sdk manager then creating a new app and choosing install option from the new app wizard worked for me. It's a location issue I think and re-installing from the new app wizard takes care of the problem.