# Can't find Android Support Libary in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

problem already explained in the topic. I already looked at:

- [Can't find Android Compatibility Package on SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975870/cant-find-android-compatibility-package-on-sdk-manager)
- [Can't find Android Support Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437183/cant-find-android-support-package)
- [Cant' find Android Support package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243030/cant-find-android-support-package)
- [Android Support package not present in SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244091/android-support-package-not-present-in-sdk-manager)
- [Cannot find Support Package in Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038841/cannot-find-support-package-in-android-sdk-manager)
- [cannot find android support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341305/cannot-find-android-support-library)

I made a screenshot with the things I can see:

[image]

Furthermore I'm using NetBeans. Hope you can help me

Comment: Still a few more links to check: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428142/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-androidruntimenoretrolamb/41429174#41429174) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133317/javafxports-android-gradle-task-requires-android-support-library-which-is-re)

Comment: AFAIK, that SDK Manager is no longer supported. Your choices are the Android Studio SDK Manager or possibly [the `sdkmanager` tool](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/12/12/sdkmanager-command-line-sdk-installs.html). Also, AFAIK, Google discontinued distributing standalone copies of the Android Support Library. "I'm using NetBeans" -- see if there is support for Maven-style artifacts in NetBeans. If so, the Android Support Repository will be your source for the support artifacts.

Comment: Does NetBeans even support Android development?

Answer (score 0):

[Download me](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/support_r23.2.1.zip)

Download, unzip it and put it into the androids sdk\extras\android Folder. Than the Android Support Library should show up